# Populate Cell Based on Multiple Criteria including day of week

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to populate Column E to determine on-time/late notice based on day-of-week request was provided and number of days notice was provided before date needed.

```
Column A: Date Requested
Column B: Date Needed
Column C: # of Days Notice
Column D: Day of Week Notice Provided
Column E: On-Time/Late
```

```
    A         B         C         D         E
5/1/2016  5/10/2016     9      Sunday
5/3/2016  5/11/2016     8      Tuesday
5/5/2016  5/15/2016     10     Thursday
5/11/2016 5/12/2016     1      Wednesday
5/12/2016 5/15/2016     3      Thursday
```

The criteria for determining if something is on-time or late is as follows:

```
Column G: Day of Week
Column H: # of Days Required for On-Time Notice

     G          H
   Sunday       8    
   Monday       7  
   Tuesday      6    
   Wednesday    12  
   Thursday     11   
   Friday       10 
   Saturday     9
```

Example: If the notice was provided on Thursday but only 6 days in advance, I need Column E to show "Late". However, if the request was on Thursday and 12 days in advance, I need it to show "On-Time".

Anyone with any good ideas? I'm sure it can be done, but my excel skills aren't that advanced.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you started from second row

use this formula in E2 copied down

```
=IF(AND(D2=$G$2,C2>=$H$2),"On time",IF(AND(D2=$G$3,C2>=$H$3),"On time",IF(AND(D2=$G$4,C2>=$H$4),"On time",IF(AND(D2=$G$5,C2>=$H$5),"On time",IF(AND(D2=$G$6,C2>=$H$6),"On time",IF(AND(D2=$G$7,C2>=$H$7),"On time",IF(AND(D2=$G$8,C2>=$H$8),"On time","Late")))))))
```

Regards

Comment: Worked like a charm! I think I got myself stuck in a logic loop somehow but this is exactly what I was trying to get to. Thanks a lot!